How to add Multiple Images in ASP.Net Core MVC CFA(code first approach)
I'am using Generic Collection List but not working
public class Product
{
[Key]
public int p_id { get; set; }
public string p_name { get; set; }
public double p_price { get; set; }
public List<string> p_image { get; set; }

public int cat_id { get; set; }

public Category category { get; set; }

}
Solve This How to add Multiple Images in ASP.Net Core MVC CFA(code first approach)
public class Product
{
[Key]
public int p_id { get; set; }
public string p_name { get; set; }
public double p_price { get; set; }
public List<string> p_image { get; set; }

public int cat_id { get; set; }

public Category category { get; set; }

}

What you mean the add the multiple images?  Do you mean you want to upload multiple images as bytes to the database by using the EF code first?

I am Supposing that List<string> p_image contains the images paths :
Create a class (ex : ProductImage) with property string Path {get;set;}  inside it (and do not forget the primary key),
then replace List<string> p_image { get; set; } with List<ProductImage> p_image { get; set; }
because, when using an object, the EF core will tell the DB to create a table that have 3 columns, the Id (image's id), the Path, and ProductId (Foreign key to the Products table, created by convention), so it can create a 1-to-M relationship,
but when you use just a string, it will not work, because you do not have the Foreign Key, so no 1-to-M relationship is possible, it will work only if you have single image (1-to-1 relationship) so the path at this case is a column at the Product's table, not at a independent table
and read the docs for better understanding

Bonus : the naming convention on C# is Pascal case for public props, and mostly there is no need for additional context (p_ or cat_)

The result should be like this :
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    
    // Replace List<string> with List<ProductImage>
    public List<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class ProductImage
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }

    // Foreign Key to Product
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}


Can you provide the code

I added the code, I hope it is useful, + you can easily get it from chatgpt (as I did) if you send your quesion with my answer to it
